# How to exclude library jars during build process from android library project aar artifacts?

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

I have Android Library Project and I have to generate aar artifacts without including any jars from libs directory in my project.

One of the approach I thought is extracting classes.jar from aar file and then use classes.jar as a dependency in other projects.

Is there a better way ?

I use following plugin to generate aar

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'
```

Answer (score 0):

Roughly the same idea, but after you run uploadArchives, you can run this gradle task:

```
task makeJarRelease(type: Copy) {
  from("build/intermediates/bundles/release/")
  into("release/")
  include("classes.jar")
  rename("classes.jar", "somename.jar")
  println "made jar"
}
```

That jar is the same jar that will be in your .aar file, so long as you run uploadArchives first. I had this step:

`makeJarRelease.dependsOn(uploadArchives)`

Used to use it back when I supported eclipse with my library. Hope it helps!